# Inserting random strings with awk - array or for loop?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm creating a playlist like this:

```
promo="/videos/promo.mp4"
/usr/bin/shuf playlist.m3u | awk -v n=5 '1; NR % n == 0 { print "'$promo'" }' | tee playlist.m3u archives/playlist.m3u > /dev/null
```

This works great, but I would like to:

1) Have multiple promos videos to choose from, so that it isn't the same promo every 5 videos

2) Have n also be a random number, so that it isn't exactly every 5 videos, more like a random number between 2 and 6.

I can get a list of videos from a promos folder with

```
  ls -d -1 "$PWD/"**
```

Do I need a for loop for this? Should I store all the promo videos in an array? Am I approaching this all wrong?

Comment: your ideas will definitely work, but read the man page for the `shuf` utility and see if it already has controls that you need. You might just `ls *.mp4 *.promos > files ; shuf -special_options files` and get results you can work with. Sorry, don't have more time for this. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/shuf playlist.m3u | awk 'BEGIN {srand(); r = 6; p = 0} NR == FNR {promos[p++] = $0; next} {print} ++c == r {print promos[int(rand() * length(promos))]; r = int(rand()*5+2); c = 0}' <(find /videos -type f -name 'promo*.mp4') -
```

Broken out for readability:

```
/usr/bin/shuf playlist.m3u | awk 'BEGIN {srand(); r = 6; p = 0} 
    NR == FNR {promos[p++] = $0; next}
    {print}
    ++c == r {
        print promos[int(rand() * length(promos))];
        r = int(rand()*5+2); c = 0
    }' <(find /videos -type f -name 'promo*.mp4') -
```

The AWK command reads the output of `find` (a list of promo files) into an array using Bash process substitution. The `NR == FNR` clause loops (`next`) through each of the file names until the list is completely read (`FNR` resets to 1).

Then it reads the output of the `shuf` command from `STDIN` through the `-` argument and prints each line. If the counter equals the random number (the first time it uses the number `r` is assigned in the `BEGIN` clause), then print a random selection from the array. Calculate a new random number between 2 and 6 for the promo interval and reset the counter to 0.

Example output:

```
song14.ext
song6.ext
song21.ext
song18.ext
song9.ext
song11.ext
/videos/promo8.ext
song2.ext
song20.ext
song27.ext
/videos/promo4.ext
song8.ext
```

(bogus filenames with bogus extensions)

You could pass the range into the command using AWK's `-v` arguments.

Comment: Thank you for this. When I run it, I get `awk: line 5: illegal reference to array promos` and 
`./plmaker: line 93: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied` I'm using mawk 1.3.3, not sure if that makes a difference?

Comment: @screamingdrills: `mawk` doesn't support `length()` for arrays. Since the first clause is already counting the elements as they're assigned, we can use that count instead. Just change `rand() * length(promos)` to `rand() * p`. As for the other error, perhaps the user account running the script doesn't have write access to the directory `/dev/fd` or `/proc/self/fd` or similar which is weird but may occur if part of the process is running as one user and another part as another user. Are you using `sudo` to run any of it?

Comment: ok great, that fixed the first error. As for the second error, it must have been a syntax error on my part. I rewrote the last few lines and it works now, thank you so much!